# Making a Batch Post to OData API (Working with D365 F&O specifically)

Tags: python, post, odata, batch-processing

I am attempting to make a API call to OData endpoint as a batch, however, I am receiving an error back regarding an invalid character in my request, I have checked the formatting against an example here: https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/

and even tried to implement the headers in odata-version-4-0 however, nothing I have tried seems to be successful.

Using Python to make the request:

```
from MSAL_Helper import get_token
from Get_Config import Get_Config

import requests

config = Get_Config()
token = get_token(config)

## ENDPOINTS ##

urlEnvBase = f'{config["FOEnv"]}'
url = f"{urlEnvBase}/data/$batch"

## Requests for System Users
dataentity = "PersonUsers"

boundary = "batch_l4tM9q_hNs818_iguGqN" ##TO DELETE
headers = {
    'Content-Type': f'multipart/mixed; boundary={boundary}',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    "Authorization": token
}

body = """
--batch_l4tM9q_hNs818_iguGqN
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST PersonUsers HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
{
    "UserId":"JEREMYL",
    "PartyNumber":"000000104",
    "ValidFrom":"1900-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "UserEmail":"JEREMYL@contosoax7.onmicrosoft.com",
    "PersonNameAlias":"Jeremy Los",
    "ValidTo":"2154-12-31T23:59:59Z"
}
--batch_l4tM9q_hNs818_iguGqN--

resp = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)

print(resp.headers)
print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

The response I get form the call is

```
--batchresponse_fb224951-bc3c-4210-a534-bac45b3db181
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
OData-Version: 4.0

{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"An error has occurred.","innererror":{
      "message":"Unexpected character encountered while parsing '' `value: A. Path , line 0, position 0.", ....`
```